# "I am done with school for now." vs "I am done for now with school."

Tags: grammar

Is the second sentence incorrect, and if so, why?

Comment: Ths second sentence isn't so much wrong as clumsy. When I read it my brain had to correct its initial interpretation of "I am [**done for**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/done_for) now..." to the same meaning as the first sentence.

Comment: @Weather Vane You should just write an answer...

Comment: One might say "For now I'm done with school", but probably not "I'm done for now with school'.  Though if asked "Are you going to school?" replying "I'm done for now" would be idiomatic.

Comment: How is that about anything other than personal choice of style?

Since you're here, your first does not and your second does need commas.

Does that much make sense to you?